# MYSQL Docker container gives "unknown database" error

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm using a docker container for MySQL with docker-compose that works just fine.

The only problem is that I get the error `unknown database "database_name"` the first time I run it every day (after Windows startup)

After that, if I stop it and re-run it I get no errors and everything works fine.

**yaml configuration:**

```
version: "2.0"
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --max_allowed_packet=32505856
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - 'C:\data\mysql_db:/var/lib/mysql/'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    networks:
      - shared
networks:
  shared: 
    external:
      name: shared
```

**EDIT**: here is a pastebin of the logs of a startup: https://pastebin.com/aJiKJ4aE

Comment: Maybe adding `MYSQL_DATABASE: database_name` in environment would help ?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm working with multiple databases and none of them is recognized

Comment: Do you get the error from startup?  Not from connecting and trying to do some queries?

Comment: Yes, from startup (and also if I try to connect consequently)

Comment: What is in 'docker logs mysql'?

Comment: I'm uploading them now

Comment: Have you checked, that /var/lib/mysql has the right Directory/File Permissions?

Comment: I believe that would not explain why restarting the container works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're experiencing [this problem](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/584). There's a couple possible solutions there, but I haven't tried them myself as I don't have Docker on Windows:

1. [Solution 1 by shayne](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/584#issuecomment-394056400)
   Remove `restart:always` from your container. Instead run this command once, it'll create a container that will start your container when the mount is ready:

```
docker run --name holdup
    --restart always
    -v 'C:\data\mysql_db:/var/lib/mysql/'
    -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    shaynesweeney/holdup
```

This will however have an effect of starting *all* your stopped containers on reboot.

2. [Solution 2 by evolart](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/584#issuecomment-474144098)
   Create the following Powershell script (adjust your location to where your docker-compose.yml is):

```
Do {
    $dockerps = (docker ps)
    Start-Sleep -S 5
} While (! $dockerps -contains "mysql")
Set-Location D:\Docker\MySQL
docker-compose restart
```

Then:

> Add a Task Scheduler Task with the action Start a program to run the script.
>   Program/script: powershell.exe
>   Add arguments: -windowstyle hidden -file D:\Docker\MySQL-Restart.ps1

Comment: I'm facing similar issue almost once a month. What I'm doing for now is to run DB backup script from host  

`docker exec -i mysql_test mysql -uroot -ptest </home/some_user/db_backups/backup_2019-06-21.sql`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no such a schema in your database container instance. What you can do is:

- run the app
- open your mysql workbench and connect to your db container instance using the binding port ( you can also create the schema using the command line)
- create the schema "database_name"
- create table and insert date(optional)
- finally restart your docker app

You should be able to access the container db now.

check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5J3rtAGGNU) if you don't know how to connect to the database container using the workbench